# Mongodb two nodes deployment

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I know Mongodb suggest the replication set minimum is 3

Can I use two servers to install Mongodb with 4 replication sets in order to prevent Write failure when one node down?

My idea is to install two more instances on each server to fake/get rid of it:

- Mongodb 1

  - Replcation set 1 (Master)
  - Replcation set 2 (Secondary)
- Mongodb 2

  - Replcation set 3 (Secondary)
  - Replcation set 4 (Arbiter)

If one server down, it still has two replication sets for it.

Can anyone can comment my idea?
I would like to know is there any issue/risk needed to consider?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad idea. Your suggested configuration would be counter-productive for two main reasons:

1. Running [two instances of MongoDB on the same hosts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/configuration/#run-multiple-database-instances-on-the-same-system) will lead to them both running slowly and awkwardly, competing for memory, cpu, disk i/o, etc.
2. If one of the hosts goes down, the two nodes on the other will *not* be able to continue the replica set because with only two nodes running out of four, you don't have the [majority necessary to become primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/).

MongoDB is [intended to be run effectively on multiple hosts](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-architecture), so it is designed for that; even if you could find a way to shoe-horn a functioning replica set onto only two hosts, you would be working against MongoDB's design and struggling to make it work effectively.

Really, your best option is to run a single mongod instance on each of your two hosts, and to run an arbiter on a third (separate) host; that kind of [normal 3-host configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/) is an effective and straightforward way of achieving both data replication and high availability.

Comment: 1) Performance is not an issue for it. 
2) I am thinking to add up 6 nodes and 3 nodes in each side

Comment: OK, I see your point from the URL https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-architectures/

Even if how I try to produce the number of node is both servers, the Fault Tolerance number cannot be a half of members total. (That's mean if I shutdown one of the server, it doesn't have enough majority to elect a new primary). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/

Even number of members in a set is not recommended. The only reason to add an Arbiter is to resolve this issue and increase number of members by 1 to make it odd. It makes no sense to add 2 Arbiters at all.

Similarly there is no point to put an Arbiter to the same server with any other member. It is quite lightweight, so you can co-locate it with an application server for example.

Having 2 db servers the best replica set configuration would be:

- Mongodb 1

  - Master
- Mongodb 2

  - Secondary
- Any other server

  - Arbiter

Comment: I am not going to add 2 arbiters in it. just one arbiter

Comment: And I want to deploy two nodes only MongoDB with failover support. This idea comes up and it seems resolve the issue (Single Mongodb instance will become Readonly)

Comment: I must get the question wrong, but I read it as you are trying to create a replica set with 4 members, one of which is an arbiter co-located with a secondary, which is wrong. Number of members should be odd.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, no you cannot do it..

Reason is "majority". If you loose one server of those two, you don't have majority of votes online.

This is reason, why 3 is minimum. It can be 3 data bearing nodes or 2 data bearing nodes and one arbiter. All of those have one vote and if you loose one of those, replica set still have 2/3 votes what is majority. Like 3/5 or 4/7.

Values 1/2 (or 2/4) are not majority.